# SpriteKit/Swift: Variable is being reset without reason

Tags: xcode, ios7, swift, sprite-kit

I have created a scene in SpriteKit, with a SKNode called "World" within it. I'd like to set the y-Position of the world-Node. In order to do this I have created a function, but it didn't seem to work. Therefore I have isolated to problem to this: I create a new variable called worldYPosition. In the didMoveToView set it to a random first value (for testing). When a button is touched the worldScrollTo function is called and given the argument "5000.0". This function is supposed to set the the worldYPosition to the given Argument, and apparently it does just that. However when the worldYPosition is printed by the update function, suddenly it is set to 0.0, and can't be changed anymore. No other function or anything else is accessing the value.

```
class UnderwaterWorld: SKScene {
    // Vars        
    var worldYPosition : CGFloat?

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        // Create the world
        self.addChild(world)

        worldYPosition = 1234823
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        println("WorldYPosition within update: \(worldYPosition!)")
    }

    func worldScrollTo(pos : CGFloat) {
        println("Position to set to: \(pos)")
        worldYPosition = pos
        println("New WorldYPosition: \(worldYPosition!)")
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
"WorldYPosition within update: 1234823.0"
"Button calls worldScrollTo with pos 5000.0"
"Position to set to: 5000.0"
"New WorldYPosition: 5000.0"
"WorldYPosition within update: 0.0"
```

I have found other people with problems to set the position.y of a SKNode, those problems seem to be related to a physicsBody, but that can't be the problem here. I have absolutely no idea why my code behaves so strange. Help would be really appreciated!

Best greets,
C

**EDIT (Additional Information + Simplified Code)**

Here is some more code, that is less reduced:

UnderwaterWorld.swift:

```
import SpriteKit

class UnderwaterWorld: SKScene {
    // Vars
    var world = SKNode()
    var ceratiasCarunculatus1 : CeratiasCarunculatus?
    var ceratiasBispinosus1 : CeratiasBispinosus?
    var halosaurusMachroir1 : HalosaurusMachroir?

    var worldYPosition : CGFloat?

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        // Create the world
        self.addChild(world)

        ceratiasCarunculatus1 = CeratiasCarunculatus(idIs: 0, sizeIs: 0.9, speedIs: 0.7, turnLeftIs: 1400, turnRightIs: 0, animationTimeIs: 7.22);
        ceratiasCarunculatus1!.position = CGPointMake(800,-300)
        world.addChild(ceratiasCarunculatus1)

        ceratiasBispinosus1 = CeratiasBispinosus(idIs: 1, sizeIs: 0.9, speedIs: 1, turnLeftIs: 1400, turnRightIs: 0, animationTimeIs: 6.84);
        ceratiasBispinosus1!.position = CGPointMake(0,-600)
        world.addChild(ceratiasBispinosus1)

        halosaurusMachroir1 = HalosaurusMachroir(idIs: 1, sizeIs: 2, speedIs: 1, turnLeftIs: 1400, turnRightIs: 0, animationTimeIs: 10);
        halosaurusMachroir1!.position = CGPointMake(1400,-0)
        world.addChild(halosaurusMachroir1)

        //var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, target: self, selector: Selector("scrollWorld"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        //worldScrollTo(-900)

        worldYPosition = 1234823
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        ceratiasCarunculatus1!.update()
        ceratiasBispinosus1!.update()

        halosaurusMachroir1!.update()

        println(worldYPosition!)
        self.world.position.y = worldYPosition
    }

    override func didSimulatePhysics()  {
    }

    func worldScrollTo(pos : CGFloat) {
        println("pos: \(pos)")
        worldYPosition = pos
        println("unten: \(worldYPosition!)")
    }
}
```

MainViewController (the value of the variable deepness (Int) is declared by a draggable button. That part works, as a println has shown me. In the update function of the MVC the function mentioned above is called):

```
var underWaterWorld = UnderwaterWorld()
underWaterWorld.worldScrollTo(CGFloat(deepness))
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you are attempting to position a node after setting a physics body to it.

Comment: As I mentioned the node doesn't have or need a physicsBody – I have even tried setting the physicsBody to nil, without ever having created it. But still: this wouldn't explain why a variable that is completely unrelated to the node (as I tried to create one in my example) is being reset, would it? Thanks you for you answer though!

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I will try to make the code comprehensible and post in just a minute …

Comment: I had assumed you were setting the property based on the node position, along with the confusion of what your said about a physics body. Are you sure it's the same instance of UnderwaterWorld where you call worldScrollTo and update?